# OnClick JavaScript id issue

Tags: apex, javascript, record, list-button

I am using a List custom button in Listview once I select the records through checkboxes then the script will call and get the list of id's and pass them to apex class methods, but at that point I am getting not the id's.

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Sample__c)};
var prodRecorIds= "";

if (records[0] == null) {
  alert("You have not selected any record.");
} else {
  for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
     prodRecorIds += records[i] + ",";
  }
}
sforce.apex.execute("ListviewController","updateEuro",{prodids:"{+ prodRecorIds}"});
window.location.reload();
```

I am passing the list of id's in +prodRecorIds in execute method, but I didn't get the id. Instead of ids it passes the `'prodRecorIds'` string. How can I resolve this issues?

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing prodRecordsIds correctly.

in execute method :

Replace

```
prodids:"{+ prodRecorIds}"
```

with

```
prodids:"{"+ prodRecorIds+"}"
```

Always check error console while working with javascript.